# Refactor down into a single model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I have built myself a photo gallery system for my site but it's tied pretty much 1:1 with Flickr, now, in itself this isn't a huge problem but I would now like to refactor it down a bit and the first thing I want to attempt is to see if I can collapse some existing models into one.

Currently, I have the following models:

```
Collection
Album
Photo
Photo-size
```

Here are the full associations of each:

```
Collection
has_many :children, class_name: "Collection", foreign_key: "parent_id"
belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Collection", foreign_key: "parent_id"
has_many :albums

Album
has_many :photos, :dependent => :destroy
belongs_to :collection

Photo
belongs_to :album
has_many :photo_sizes, :dependent => :destroy

Photo_size
belongs_to :photo
```

It all works but I would like some thoughts from the people on here to find out your opinions on ways I should go about this.

For example, It seems, in my head (anyway), that I could collapse Collections down into Albums and then as a secondary thing after, collapse Photo_sizes down into Photos.

What I am getting confused with is how the relationships will work in the merged Collection/Albums model as an Album needs to be able to have child albums but one should also be a top level collection and one should also be able to have a number of photos.

An album holding other albums will not have photos as well. So an album with EITHER have children albums OR a set of photos.

Any thoughts on how I could go about this?

Comment: Why? Fewer models != better. In terms of Flickr, Collections are not Albums, and Albums are not Collections. Trying to represent them with one model is wrong. Same with Photos and Photo_size (which should be PhotoSize, by the way)

Comment: Sorry, When I said mapped pretty much 1:1 I have Collections = Flickr Collections and Albums = Flickr Photosets, oh and I do have the sizes as PhotoSize. My mistake there. I just thought it might be best moving them as one model. Maybe not then. Thanks

Comment: How do I accept the first comment as the answer?